# How to check, that "ID" which i put from textbox does not exist in my MySql table?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

This is my code. When I enter an ID which doesn't exist, an error message appears. I'd like to show a messagebox when the program realizes that this ID does not exist.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void BTN_INSERT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String selectquery = "SELECT * FROM imgbase.Clients WHERE ID = '" + BOX_ID.Text + "' ";
        command = new MySqlCommand(selectquery, connection);


        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(table);


        BOX_FULLNAME.Text = table.Rows[0][1].ToString();

        BOX_INFO.Text = table.Rows[0][2].ToString();

        byte[] img = (byte[])table.Rows[0][3];

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        da.Dispose();



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ID` doesn't exists then you will fetch 0 rows or records. In such case you can check `Rows` property of your `DataTable` like

```
if(table.Rows.Count == 0)
  MessageBox.Show("No Records with given ID ...");
```

BTW, stop using concatenated query with user input which is vulnerable to *SQL Injection* rather use parameterized query using `SqlParameter`

```
    String selectquery = "SELECT * FROM imgbase.Clients WHERE ID = @ID";
    command = new MySqlCommand(selectquery, connection);
    MySqlParameter param  = new MySqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ID";
    param.Value         = Convert.ToInt32(BOX_ID.Text.Trim());
    command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

After you fill your datatable Just check for the returned rows count. If rows fetched then do your processing else throw message and return to caller back.

```
da.Fill(table);
if(table.Rows.Count == 0)
{
  MessageBox.Show("No Records with given ID ...");
  return;
}

//Rows present and thus do processing
```

Answer (score 1):

and so you can use

```
try{
   if(table.Rows.Count == 0)
      { MessageBox.Show("No Records with given ID ...");
        return;
       }
 }
 catch{
 error message;
}
```